# yum is corrupted in fedora 19

Tags: fedora, yum, repository

I am trying to install any package or doing yum update but getting below issues.
Earlier it was running fine

```
[root@xyz-db2 ~]# yum update


File contains no section headers.
file: file://///etc/yum.repos.d/bintray-sbt-rpm.repo, line: 2
'<!doctype html>\n'
```

Comment: The contents of that file may help debug what is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like you have downloaded a `.html` file instead of a `.repo` file, which is not valid.

Remove the `/etc/yum.repos.d/bintray-sbt-rpm.repo` file, it is useless anyways and try to download the `bintray-sbt-rpm.repo` again from where you got it.
Before copying it to `/etc/yum.repos.d`, have a look at that file and compare it to other files in that directory to check if the syntax may be valid.